# Swift 4.2 - Value of type '(____) -> () -> (____)' has no member 'childNode'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I created a custom class in swift to manage my main menu for a game I'm making I linked it to the SKScene file and tried to create a constant to access the variable and I got this error: Cannot use instance member 'childNode' within property initializer.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class MainMenu: SKScene {

    let startGameButton:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "SpriteName")

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    }
}
```

Does anyone know whats happening? If not is there another way to access sprites.

Comment: You have to run the line inside a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial values for `let` variables must be constants that can be initialized before the `init()` method is executed. That in turn means they can't reference `self`.

One workaround for that is making them `lazy` instance variables, which get initialized when they are first used (which, by definition, can't happen before `init()` has returned a reference to the object). In that case, the lazy variable would be initialized with the result from a closure.

Change:

```
let startGameButton:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "SpriteName")
```

to

```
lazy var startGameButton:SKSpriteNode = self.childNode(withName: "SpriteName") as! SKSpriteNode
```